# State is updating but Images are not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am fetching images from an API but when fetch it update the state in react but does not render in nested Card. but when click another list it updates the card and render images.
here is my code

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.fetch()
    }
```

this is the fetch method called on component did mount and when pagination changes

```
fetch = (params = {}) => {
        let lang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
        let accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
        let tokenType = localStorage.getItem("tokenType");
        let clientId = localStorage.getItem("clientId")
        let sortOrder = 'DESC'
        let img_id;
        let page = params.page || this.state.current;
        let data = {
            clientId: clientId,
            page: page - 1,
            size: 8,
            lang,
            name: params.name || '',
            nameAr: params.arabicname || '',
            description: params.description || '',
            sortColumn: 'baseUom.name',
            sortOrder: ''
        }
        var arrayList;
        console.log(data)
        var authImageOptions;

        const self = this
        var imgUrl = []
        axios({
            url: API_URL + 'productsByClient',
            method: 'POST',
            data,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': tokenType + ' ' + accessToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data.data)
            arrayList = [...data.data.content]
            console.log(arrayList)
            arrayList.map((item, i) => {
                if (item.prodImg) {
                    authImageOptions = {
                        method: 'GET',
                        responseType: 'blob',
                        url: API_URL + 'getImage',
                        params: {
                            imageId: item.prodImg,
                            lang: localStorage.getItem("lang")
                        },
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': tokenType + ' ' + accessToken
                        }
                    }
                    axios(authImageOptions)
                        .then(function (response) {
                                var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
                                reader.onload = () => {

                                    imgUrl[i] = reader.result

                                }
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            message.error(error.response.data.message);
                        });
                    } else {
                        imgUrl[i] = ''

                }
            })
            self.setState({
                productList: arrayList,
                totalPageItem: data.data.totalElements / 8 * 10,
                imgUrl
            })
         }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })}

{this.state.productList.map((item, key) => (

                                <Col span={6}
                                key={key}
                                >
                                     <Card style={{ height: '180px', marginTop: '20px' }}
                                        hoverable                                                
                                        cover={<img src={localStorage.getItem("myImage"[key])} alt="Product Image" style={{ height: '80px', width: '200px !important' }} />}
                                    >
                                        <p style={{ fontSize: 'small', fontWeight: 650, textAlign: 'center' }}>{item.name} </p>
                                    </Card>
                                </Col>

                            ))
                        }
```

I am extreamly sorry if my english is not good but I really need help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem will propably be in calling async call inside map function on your arrayList (axios(authImageOptions)). Btw you are using map only for iterating through array. That seems weird to me. If you want just iterate use forEach. But my advice is to use map to map arrayList to array of promises and then wait on all of them to be resolved with Promise.All before you continue with setting state.

Comment: well I was trying almost same but it was not working but now it is working,
Thank You very much